# after effects timeline in compositions

Tags: after-effects

Im trying to edit my first video in after effects. When I include a video in compositions a green bar is included and gives me the chance to display only 15segs of video and then loops again the same part of the video.

[image]

everytime i try to change that information the bar is regenerated.

my main question is:

its possible to change that green bar in the right side of the image, to avoid the 15segs limit?

thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time you can preview depends on your available RAM. The green line means "This is the part that is already rendered into your RAM". You can edit the amount of RAM available for After Effects under:

Preferences > Memory

Answer (score 1):

try this solutions

1- use lower resolution (see the image 1) choose

*half (un demi) extend time limit 4 time

*third (un tiere) to extend it 9 time

*quarter (un quart) to extend it 16 time!

remember that this affect the quality but you can change it at any time

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHEv8.png)

2- use lower frame rate (first case in image 2)

or ignore some frames (second case) make it equal to 1 or 2

remember again that this can have a stroboscopic effect to your video but you can

change it at any time

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTljY.png)